# displaying address location with google maps onload

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I'm trying to currently show the location of an address when page loads, but my map doesn't show at all. I tried to alert(address) and it works. It shows the correct address I'm trying to get. But I'm not sure if I'm doing this right?

```
<script>
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    //var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            var city_state_zip = document.getElementById("city_state_zip").innerHTML;
            var street_address = document.getElementById("street_address").innerHTML;
            var address = street_address + " " + city_state_zip;//document.getElementById(street_addres +" "+ city_state_zip).value;
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            });
          }



    window.onload = function(){
            codeAddress();
       }
</script>
```

I combined the initialize() with the codeAddress() found in this example: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#GeocodingStatusCodes The reason I want to combine this because I dont want to load the map with a random LatLng, and I want it to load with a address I have already.

Does anyone have any idea if I'm even doing this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you have the latlng commented out Im not sure if that will cause a problem.  Also, were you able to display the map without all the geocoding?

Comment: when I uncomment the latlng, it goes to that specific latlng, then it goes straight to the address desired, how do i not allow it to go to the latlng and just go straight to address onload?

Comment: do all the geocoder stuff before you set the map options and use results[0].geometry.location to populate the center property of the options

Comment: I think that was one of my problems, I'm not sure how to set up the geocode to LatLng, so it can populate based on my address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following modification of the script makes it work for those who was in the same boat as me. This now allows me to load a specific address when the page is loaded, it will automatically detect the lat,lng from my html.

This is a slight modification from the google's website.

```
<script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var lat='';
    var lng=''
    var city_state_zip = document.getElementById("city_state_zip").innerHTML;
    var street_address = document.getElementById("street_address").innerHTML;
    var address = street_address + " " + city_state_zip;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); //getting the lat
       lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); //getting the lng
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
           position: results[0].geometry.location
       });
     } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
     });
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: latlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
     }


window.onload = function(){
       codeAddress();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Then you should edit this answer with the working code and accept your own answer! That's better than the question and answer being together

Comment: I will put the working code here, but I can't accept it until a few days later